# Source passwords from multiple .htpasswd files for a single directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a web application that I need to use Apache's password protection to protect.  Is it possible to have each user have their own .htpasswd file?  I tried the following, but it only used the second .htpasswd file:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/user1/.htpasswd
AuthUserFile /home/user2/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
```

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible ,
but you have to set all **username** and **password** in one single ***.htpasswd*** file.

like i have 2 user with username

1. jhon
2. michael

And password

1. 123456
2. 456789

so now my **.htpasswd** file is as follow

jhon:$apr1$C3vsmc.6$BpCDWefwB3X01BH0jwnF5/
michael:$apr1$X.wCDi.r$5QhNyIvXKXJT1K9glEaLr.

you have to set both users **username** and **password** in one ***.htpasswd*** file

Hope it is useful.